# Passing button id in history.push() in React

Tags: react-router, browser-history

I two buttons as pictured below. I am navigating users to the registration page using `history.push` using this code. I want to pass some sort of data to the `Registration` page like if the user is a "volunteer" or "good cause" based on the button click. I know that it is relatively simple but I cannot figure it out. Thanks.

[image]

```
let history = useHistory();
  const handleClickRegistration = () => {
    history.push({
      pathname: '/Registration',
    });
  };
```

This is where I am calling the function

```
          type="submit"
          variant="contained"
          id="volunteer"
          className={classes.button}
          style={{margin: 8}}
          onClick={handleClickRegistration}
        >
      Register as a Volunteer
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using the same function on both buttons then use it like

```
<Button onClick={()=> handleClickRegistration("volunteer")} >Register as a 
Volunteer</Button>

<Button onClick={()=> handleClickRegistration("good_cause")} >Register as a 
Good Cause</Button>
```

and in handleClickRegistration function send a state in history.push method

```
const handleClickRegistration = (userType) => {
history.push({
  pathname: '/Registration',
  state: { userType: userType }
});
};
```

which you can get in Registration rotue